# Read iOS toast message through Appium

Tags: java, selenium, appium, appium-ios

Could anyone suggest to me the code to read an iOS toast message. I have read android toast messages using AndroidElement toastElement = driver.findElementByXPath("//android.widget.Toast[1]");
        String toastMessage = toastElement.getAttribute("name");

But for iOS toast the above is not working

IOSElement toastElement = driver.findElementByXPath("//ios.widget.Toast[1]");
        String toastMessage = toastElement.getAttribute("name");

Answer (score 2):

Use below method , it uses page source to verify the toast message.
Works for both iOS and Android.

```
public boolean isToastMessageDisplayed(String message)
{
    boolean isDisplayed = false;
    int count=0;
    do {
        if(mobileDriver.getPageSource().contains(message))
        {
            isDisplayed=true;
            break;
        }
        Thread.sleep(200);//Add your custom wait if exists
        count++;

    }while(count<10);
    return isDisplayed;
}
```